# I keep creating Multiple child objects when I connect a single object to the parent object

Tags: objects, parent

For example when I try to connect a cube (child) to the body mesh (parent) I end up getting multiple cubes in the shape of the mesh. How do I stop creating multiple child objects?

Comment: hard to understand, please show some screenshots of what's happening

Comment: Do you have dupliverts turned on? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/verts.html